# how to not print scalebar and how to print the zoom bar that shows on map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cartography, printing, zoom

I am using javascript api for ArcGIS and need to print the zoom bar on map, but don't want the scale information to be printed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to remove the scalebar from the layout in the .MXD that is used as a template for your print service.

if you are using the default utility print service (installed with ArcGIS Server 10.1 and above) the templates can be found in

```
.install dir\ArcGIS\Server\Templates\ExportWebMapTemplates
```

Comment: with regard to printing the zoombar, i don't know of a way to do this and can't say i understand why it would be helpful to include it in static output.